# Locating the org hosting the Connected App based on consumer key

Tags: connected-apps

I have a consumer key, and a consumer secret, and I have checked every Connected App in the main org as well as every Sandbox but cannot find the source of said key.

Is there a way to find it? Or perhaps, does anything else beside a Connected App in Salesforce produce a key and secret?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? It might be an app hosted by the service provider in their own org. Aside from looking in your own orgs, there's no way to determine where the app is hosted.

Comment: @identigral we're switching to OAuth, and cannot just switch to using a new Connected App since we still need to support the password flow for a while.

Comment: Why do you need to know where the app is hosted in order to switch or not to switch?

Answer (score 1):

Few Options if you haven't tried -

1. In the Lightning Experience

> Go to Setup -> Search App-> Go To App Manager -> Locate Your connected
> app and Click on the "down" arrow on the right side of the listed
> app-> Select View

2. Use the query and recheck your org-connected apps in descending order and match the secret key and client id.

> SELECT FIELDS(ALL) from ConnectedApplication Order by CreatedDate
> LIMIT 200

3. Use postman to check if the key and secret are working for your current org to make sure which org they belong to. Use the authentication type password for this.

Mark this as useful if you find it. :)

Comment: Hey Rajeev, thanks for the suggestions. But these steps did not give me any info that I haven't already checked. But can you elaborate a bit more on step 3? If I request a token with grant_type password, the object I get back will not give me any information about the connected app and the org it belongs to, it will only display the org the user belong to. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you meant in suggestion #3. Yes, the key and secret work, and have been used in production for years, but now I need to make small changes to that connected app, and I can't find it. Does a managed connected app generate a key and secret that I cannot easily find? because they cannot be "viewed" the same way I can view a custom connected app.

Comment: Sorry, Bilal. Not sure why you are unable to find the connected app. 

The scenario I can think of is that someone created a custom-connected app used the key and secret for API and then packaged this app to distribute it through app exchange. Now the person using this packaged version uses the same key and secret and still be able to use this connected app in their org.

Comment: I am still unable to find any reason why this will not show, maybe we're missing something here. Curious.